# Is there a better way to group rows together with names from another column

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

Is there a faster way to do create the same results here. I am trying to group rows together based on the value in column `K` with a group name in column `O`. I want to add the Group Name in column `O` to a new column

```
=IFS((K1=$P$2), $O$2,(K2=$P$3),  $O$3,(K3=$P$4), $O$4, "")
```

The formula is doing what I want it to do, but it would go all the way to K150 so I am wondering if there is a faster more efficient way to do this.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-IVir80-ZT_b9bo4tM7bibTCxZAFNkJBDYt8l0UrV44/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(K1:K150, {P2:P, O2:O}, 2, 0)))
```